# Has anyone done a Gentoo Xen Dom0/DomU update?

Tags: xen, gentoo

I am running a couple of xen 3.1.1 systems (production, test/dev) with gentoo Dom0 and DomU.  With plans to update to 3.3 soon, I am wondering if anyone has any successes or failures they'd like to share.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend making a copy of the Xen hypervisor and kernel files in '/boot'

```
mkdir /boot/3.1.1
cp -P /boot/* /boot/3.1.1/
```

that way you can maintain grub entries for the old version of Xen in case you experience problems with the new one. Though, if you do revert you may need to reinstall the old userland tools.

Using this method along with `default saved` and some strategically placed `savedefault` options in my grub config file I do remote upgrades that only require a power cycle to revert to known good version.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to it to be honest. Since there aren't really any userland tools in the DomU, it's mostly just a matter of rebooting the DomU with the updated kernel.

I recently built a new cluster of Xen servers based on openSUSE 11.1, and moving the Gentoo DomUs there was pretty much seamless.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have. It all went well, apart from [this issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/40947/xen-cant-create-domain-because-vdb-could-not-be-connected/40956#40956) that I've described with `udev`.

---

Actually this is a lie. I've just done another round of upgrades this week that were a nightmare.

I'll update this post with the details in due course.